# Declaring empty array in bash

Tags: bash

I am having my bash file like below.

```
#!/bin/sh


EXIT_CODE=0
ERROR_MESSAGES=("Error1")


ERROR_MESSAGES+=("Error1")
ERROR_MESSAGES+=("Error2")
ERROR_MESSAGES+=("Error3")
```

Getting error Text.sh: 5: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

sh Text.sh will throw error any info/suggestions here ?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not bash. `/bin/bash` is bash

Comment: No, with `#!/bin/sh` you have a POSIX shell script that does not have arrays.... (happens -- we've all been there -- about 25 years ago....)

Comment: You have to actually **use** bash in order to to use bash arrays. Run your program with `bash SCRIPTNAME`. BTW, you don't have an **empty** array in your code.